# Custom data position on the doughnut chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, chart.js

Is there any way to customize position of data I want to display in doughnut chart?
The default is that the first item in data array is placed at 0 deegres. I want it to be placed in my custom position, because I am trying to make a clock-related app.[image: Custom-default chart]

```
this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {

      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: this.titles,
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: this.times,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)'
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB"
          ]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Which part of the code?

Comment: At the moment - How you create this chart, so you can get more accurate answers to your question, based on your code, for more details, read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: charts in chart.js are created the same way everywhere so dunno why you need that but here you go

Answer (score 2):

Experiment with the `rotation` option:

```
options: {
    rotation: -0.5 * Math.PI
}
```

The value used above (`-0.5 * Math.PI`) is the default value. A value of `0` will rotate the doughnut 90° clockwise. You need a value between `0.5 * Math.PI` and `1.0 * Math.PI` in your case. More at the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options).